# Using VAE for reconstructing images

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

**Article:** https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.07047v1.pdf

**Full Code:** https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KZZuIa7Lk13ImZLJ3b-kxMfcveOPaWvN#scrollTo=XhdMfBFtzaEH

**Dataset**: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IliW9Z7s6B9VBadQ7BahFLnXLt_mmGzg/view?usp=sharing

**First Block**

```
import os
import sys
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision
import PIL.Image
import numpy as np
import tqdm

from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader, random_split
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
from torch.nn import init
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

torch.manual_seed(1)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(1)
```

**Second block**

```
real_path = "/content/targetdir/OldRealPhotos/"
x_path = "/content/targetdir/SynthOldPhotos/"
batch_size = 16 

class RealSynPhotosDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, path_r,path_x):
        self.files_r = [os.path.join(path_r, f) for f in os.listdir(path_r)]
        self.files_x = [os.path.join(path_x, f) for f in os.listdir(path_x)]

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        img_r=self.Read_image(self.files_r[index]);
        img_x=self.Read_image(self.files_x[index]);
        return img_r, img_x

    def Read_image(self,name):
        img = PIL.Image.open(name).convert('RGB')
        img = img.resize((256, 256))
        img = np.array(img)/255.0;
        img=np.transpose(img,(2,0,1)).astype('float32')
        return torch.tensor(img-0.5)

    def __len__(self):
      return min([len(self.files_r),len(self.files_x)])   # Need a better way, might not use some part of the data

# test data gen
data_set = RealSynPhotosDataset(real_path,x_path)
img1,img2=data_set.__getitem__(0);
print(img1.shape,img2.shape)
#plt.imshow(np.transpose(img,(1,2,0)))

train_len = int(len(data_set)*0.9)
train_set, test_set = random_split(data_set, [train_len, len(data_set) - train_len])

train_loader = DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False,num_workers=5)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_set, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False,num_workers=5)
```

**Third Block**

```
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

class ReNetBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,infil=64,outfil=64):
        super(ReNetBlock, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(infil, outfil, kernel_size=3, stride=1,padding=1)
        self.bn1 =  nn.InstanceNorm2d(outfil)
        self.relu1 =  nn.ReLU(False)

        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(outfil, outfil, kernel_size=3, stride=1,padding=1)
        self.bn2 = nn.InstanceNorm2d(outfil)
        self.relu2 =  nn.ReLU(False)

    def forward(self, x):
        identity = x
        out = self.conv1(x)
        out = self.bn1(out)
        out = self.relu1(out)

        out = self.conv2(out)
        out = self.bn2(out)
        out += identity
        out = self.relu2(out)

        return out


class ConvBNR(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self,in_channels,out_channels,activation=nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, False),kw=3,strides=2,pad=1):
        super(ConvBNR, self).__init__()
        self.conv1= nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=kw, stride=strides,padding=pad)
        self.bn1 =nn.InstanceNorm2d(out_channels, affine=False)
        self.activation = activation
  def forward(self,x):
        return self.bn1(self.conv1(self.activation(x)))


class TransposeConvBNR(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self,in_channels,out_channels,activation=nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, False),kw=4,strides=2,pad=1):
        super(TransposeConvBNR, self).__init__()
        self.conv1= nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=kw, stride=strides,padding=pad)
        self.bn1 =nn.InstanceNorm2d(out_channels, affine=False)
        self.activation = activation
  def forward(self,x):
        return self.bn1(self.conv1(self.activation(x)))


class VAE2_encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,in_channels=3,n_res_blocks=4,n_layers=5):
        super(VAE2_encoder, self).__init__()
        self.n_layers=n_layers
        self.layer=nn.ModuleList()
        self.layer1 = ConvBNR(in_channels,64,kw=7,pad=3,strides=1)
        for j in range(n_layers):
            self.layer.append(ConvBNR(64,64))

        self.res_blks=nn.ModuleList()
        self.n_res_blocks=n_res_blocks
        for j in range(n_res_blocks):
          self.res_blks.append(ReNetBlock(64,64))

    def forward(self, x):
        x=self.layer1(x)
        for j in range(self.n_layers):
          x= self.layer[j](x)

        for j in range(self.n_res_blocks):
           x=self.res_blks[j](x)
        return x


class VAE2_decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,in_channels=64,out_channel=3,n_res_blocks=4,n_layers=5):
        super(VAE2_decoder, self).__init__()
        self.n_layers=n_layers
        self.layer=nn.ModuleList()
        for j in range(n_layers):
            self.layer.append(TransposeConvBNR(64,64,pad=1))

        self.layer1 = nn.Conv2d(64, out_channel, kernel_size=1, stride=1)
        self.res_blks=nn.ModuleList()
        self.n_res_blocks=n_res_blocks
        for j in range(n_res_blocks):
          self.res_blks.append(ReNetBlock(64,64))

    def forward(self, x):
        for j in range(self.n_res_blocks):
           x=self.res_blks[j](x)
        
        for j in range(self.n_layers):
           # print(x.shape)
            x= self.layer[j](x)
        #print(x.shape)
        x=self.layer1(x)
        return x


class VAE2(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self,z_dim=256):
        super(VAE2, self).__init__()
        self.n_layers=2
        self.down_fact=2**self.n_layers
        down_img_size=256//self.down_fact
        self.fdim=(down_img_size)**2*64
        print('bottle neck image resolution '+str(down_img_size))
        print('bottle neck dim is '+str(self.fdim)+'..!')
        self.size=[64,down_img_size,down_img_size]
        self.encoder=VAE2_encoder(n_layers=self.n_layers)
        self.decoder=VAE2_decoder(n_layers=self.n_layers)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self.fdim, z_dim)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(self.fdim, z_dim)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(z_dim, self.fdim)

  def flat(self, input):
        return input.view(input.size(0),1, -1)

  def unflat(self, input):
        return input.view(input.size(0), self.size[0], self.size[1], self.size[2])

  def init_weights(self, init_type="xavier", gain=0.02):
      def init_func(m):
          classname = m.__class__.__name__
          if classname.find("BatchNorm2d") != -1:
              if hasattr(m, "weight") and m.weight is not None:
                  init.normal_(m.weight.data, 1.0, gain)
              if hasattr(m, "bias") and m.bias is not None:
                  init.constant_(m.bias.data, 0.0)
          elif hasattr(m, "weight") and (classname.find("Conv") != -1):
              if init_type == "normal":
                  init.normal_(m.weight.data, 0.0, gain)
              elif init_type == "xavier":
                  init.xavier_normal_(m.weight.data, gain=gain)
              elif init_type == "xavier_uniform":
                  init.xavier_uniform_(m.weight.data, gain=1.0)
              elif init_type == "kaiming":
                  init.kaiming_normal_(m.weight.data, a=0, mode="fan_in")
              elif init_type == "orthogonal":
                  init.orthogonal_(m.weight.data, gain=gain)
              elif init_type == "none":  # uses pytorch's default init method
                  m.reset_parameters()
              else:
                  raise NotImplementedError("initialization method [%s] is not implemented" % init_type)
              if hasattr(m, "bias") and m.bias is not None:
                  init.constant_(m.bias.data, 0.0)
          elif hasattr(m, "weight") and (classname.find("Linear") != -1):
              init.normal_(m.weight.data,0.0,gain)

      self.apply(init_func)
      for m in self.children():
            if hasattr(m, "init_weights"):
                m.init_weights(init_type, gain)
        
  def reparameterize(self, mu, logvar):
      std = logvar.mul(0.5).exp_()
      esp = torch.randn(*mu.size()).to(device)
      z = mu + std * esp  
      return z
  
  def bottleneck(self, h):
      mu, logvar = self.fc1(h), self.fc2(h)
      logvar=logvar*1e-3; #Lazy way to stabilize the training.
      z = self.reparameterize(mu, logvar)
      return z, mu, logvar

  def encode(self, x):
      h = self.encoder(x)
      h=self.flat(h)
      z, mu, logvar = self.bottleneck(h)
      return z, mu, logvar

  def decode(self, z):
      z = self.fc3(z)
      z_img=self.unflat(z)
      z = self.decoder(z_img)
      return z,z_img

  def forward(self, x):
      z, mu, logvar = self.encode(x)
      z,z_out = self.decode(z)
      return z, mu, logvar,z_out
```

**Final Block**

```
model=VAE2().to(device)
learning_rate = 2e-4

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(
    model.parameters(),
    lr=learning_rate, betas=(0.5, 0.999)
)

epochs = 200

l1_loss=torch.nn.L1Loss()
means=[]
logvars=[]
writer = SummaryWriter('./logs/')
steps = 1

for epoch in range(0, epochs + 1):
    # Training
    if epoch > 0:  # test untrained net first
        model.train()
        train_loss = 0
        kl_loss=0
        norm1_loss=0
        with tqdm.tqdm(train_loader, total=int(len(train_loader)), file=sys.stdout, unit="batch",position=0, leave=True) as tepoch:
          for x in tepoch:
              tepoch.set_description(f"Epoch {epoch}")
              x = x.to(device)
              x_hat, mu, logvar,z1 = model(x)

              loss1=l1_loss(x_hat, x)
              loss2 = torch.mean(0.5 * torch.sum(torch.exp(logvar) + mu**2 - 1. - logvar, 1))
              loss=loss1+loss2
              kl_loss+=loss2.item()
              norm1_loss+=loss1.item()
              train_loss += loss.item()
              writer.add_scalar("loss/l1_loss", loss1.item(), steps)
              writer.add_scalar("loss/kl_loss", loss2.item(), steps)
              steps += 1

              optimizer.zero_grad()
              loss.backward()
              optimizer.step()
              tepoch.set_postfix(loss=train_loss / len(train_loader.dataset), l1_loss=norm1_loss/ len(train_loader.dataset), kl_loss=kl_loss/ len(train_loader.dataset))
        print(f'====> Epoch: {epoch} Average loss: {train_loss / len(train_loader.dataset):.4f}')
    
    # Testing
    with torch.no_grad():
        model.eval()
        test_loss = 0.0
        for ix,x in enumerate(test_loader):
            x = x.to(device)
            x_hat, mu, logvar,_ = model(x)
            loss=0.0
            loss+=l1_loss(x_hat, x)
            loss+= torch.mean(0.5 * torch.sum(torch.exp(logvar) + mu**2 - 1. - logvar, 1))
            test_loss+=loss.item()

            if ix<1 and epoch % 5 == 0:
              plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
              for i in range(4):
                  plt.subplot(1,8,i+1)
                  plt.imshow(np.clip(x_hat.detach().cpu().numpy()[i,:,:,:].transpose(1,2,0)+0.5,0.0,1.0))
                  plt.axis('off')

              for i in range(4):
                  plt.subplot(1,8,i+1+4)
                  plt.imshow(np.clip(x.detach().cpu().numpy()[i,:,:].transpose(1,2,0)+0.5,0.0,1.0))
                  plt.axis('off')
              plt.show()

    # ===================log========================
    test_loss /= len(test_loader.dataset)
    print(f'====> Test set loss: {test_loss:.4f}')
    #display_images(x, x_hat, 1, f'Epoch {epoch}')
```

**Output:**

[image]

I have implemented the VAE2 from the above article. The reconstructed images are not that great. I tried so many things to get more valuable photos, but none worked fine, i.e learning rate, batch size, adding GAN, adding progressive GAN, reviewing each line, etc. How can I improve this code?